# Render Dynamic String as Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to render a string that is stored in my database as if it were from a CSHTML file.  Here is a sample string that I'd like to render:

```
<footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Notice that "@DateTime.Now.Year"?  Well, if this were stored in a database, how would I render this into a view and have that part of it actually render as 2014 (or whatever year it is that you're reading this)?

Comment: Just curious - why don't you use a layout or partial view?

Comment: Because this data is being pulled dynamically from the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) (NuGet package "RazorEngine") for this.

Package Manager Console:

```
PM> install-package razorengine
```

In your code:

```
string template = GetYourTemplateFromDatabase();
string content = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, null);
```

If you want to add this output to your actual view you would have to add it as an `IHtmlString` or use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Content)`:

Controller code (for `IHtmlString`):

```
ViewBag.DatabaseCode = MvcHtmlString.Create(content);
```

View code:

```
<div>
    @ViewBag.DatabaseCode
</div>
```

Comment: Answer is probably outdated. RazorEngine is some unofficial package. Unrelated to latest Razor in .NET core for instance. I think this answer does not work today however.

Answer (score 0):

you need define a model in razor 
this is a good example http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're storing that whole HTML snippet in the database? You could do a simple `String.Replace` on the string you get from the database.

```
<footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p>&copy; {{YEAR}} - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And then in the view :

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Footer.Replace("{{YEAR}}", DateTime.Now.Year))
```